# "Invalid identifier" error message for loop index (in Oracle SQL Developer)

Tags: for-loop, oracle-sqldeveloper

Why I get "invalid identifer" error message for the loop variable index (i) when running the following line?

SQL Error: ORA-00904: "I": invalid identifier

```
for i in 1..5 loop
   select Price from Orders where (ID=i);
end loop;
```

`Orders` is a table with two fields: ID and Price.

Table Orders:

```
ID   Price
------------
1     1200    
2     2250    
3     1750    
4     2000    
5     1000    
6     300
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to run it as an anonymous block?  Here's a simple example of how to get a loop working:

```
DECLARE
  v_last_name VARCHAR2(2000);

BEGIN
  for i in 1..5 loop

    WITH sample_set AS (
      SELECT 1 the_number, 'frank' last_name FROM DUAL UNION ALL
      SELECT 2 the_number, 'STEVE' last_name FROM DUAL UNION ALL
      SELECT 3 the_number, 'CARL' last_name FROM DUAL UNION ALL
      SELECT 4 the_number, 'bella' last_name FROM DUAL UNION ALL
      SELECT 5 the_number, 'tank' last_name FROM DUAL)
    select last_name
    INTO   v_last_name
    from sample_set where the_number = i;

    dbms_output.put_line(v_last_name);

  end loop;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do like this

```
DECLARE 
my_price long;
BEGIN
FOR I IN 1..5 loop
SELECT PRICE INTO MY_PRICE FROM ORDERS where id=i;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The price is'||' '||my_price);
end loop;
end;
```

---

```
OUTPUT
-------------------------------
The price is 1234
The price is 1235
The price is 1236
The price is 1237
The price is 1238

Statement processed.
```